# Unable to decompile ARM template to bicep file using either PowerShell or CLI Command

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

#### Folder/Files Structure:

[image]

**arm-storage-account.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
        "name": "testsa08",
        "location": "eastus",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Variables.ps1**:

```
$RG="bicepRG"
$subscription="<Subsricption_Id>"
$location="eastus"
```

#### For decompiling ARM to Bicep, below commands I have tried:

**02-02 Authoring, Deploying.ps1**:

**Built-in command**

```bash
az bicep decompile --file .\arm-storage-account.json
```

**Stand-alone CLI**:

```bash
bicep decompile .\arm-storage-account.json
```

**Result**:

**

```
WARNING: Decompilation is a best-effort process, as there is no guaranteed mapping from ARM JSON to Bicep.
You may need to fix warnings and errors in the generated bicep file(s), or decompilation may fail entirely if an accurate conversion is not possible.
If you would like to report any issues or inaccurate conversions, please see https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues.
```

**

**Error**:

```
C:\Users\hasher\source\repos\arm-storage-account.json: Decompilation failed with fatal error "Failed to read file:///C:/Users/hasher/source/repos/arm-storage-account.json"
```

I know the result is same for every time of decompilation but last line came as error.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the folder the command is attempting to run in.

```
Failed to read file:///C:/Users/hasher/source/repos/arm-storage-account.json
```

Your bicep file is in `repos/bicep/arm-storage-account.json`

Can either run `cd bicep` before running your command or
`bicep decompile bicep\arm-storage-account.json`